# error: Cython does not appear to be installed

Tags: python, pip, cython

Pip does not recognize Cython even though it is installed.

```
C:\Python27>python -m pip install watchdog
Collecting watchdog
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py
:315: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Na
me Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may caus
e the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation
 failures. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/s
ecurity.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py
:120: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This p
revents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL con
nections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/l
atest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Downloading watchdog-0.8.3.tar.gz (83kB)
    100% |################################| 92kB 1.2MB/s
Collecting PyYAML>=3.10 (from watchdog)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Downloading PyYAML-3.11.tar.gz (248kB)
    100% |################################| 256kB 1.3MB/s
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info\PyYAML.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info\PyYAML.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\PyYAML.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\PyYAML.egg-info\dependency_links.tx
t
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\PyYAML.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    failed to import Cython: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 applicatio
n.
    error: Cython does not appear to be installed

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\jasons\a
ppdata\local\temp\pip-build-9vxzli\PyYAML\

C:\Python27>Cython --version
Cython version 0.23.4
```

Comment: You're on windows so I'll suggest using pip to re-install cython from a prebuilt wheel or switching over to conda. Wheels are here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cython

Comment: @PaulH Well cython is installed, just I think there's a problem with paths or environmental variables. I can install watchdog from a wheel - I just wanted to try installing the regular way.

Comment: @PaulH Actually installing from a wheel doesn't work either